# Unable to automatically deploy a dotnet app to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I’m trying to deploy a test application to EB. I’m running into an issue. I followed this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-linux-core-tutorial.html

When I upload the test application, it fails to start. /var/log/eb-engine.log says

> 2022/02/07 21:59:18.585543 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [CheckProcfileForDotNetCoreApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: err
> or stat /var/app/staging/dotnet-core-tutorial: no such file or directory with file /var/app/staging/dotnet-core-tutorial

So I changed the parent directory in my source bundle so that it exported into /var/app/staging/dotnet-core-tutorial instead of /var/app/staging. Now I get this error

> 2022/02/07 22:29:51.468918 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [CheckProcfileForDotNetCoreApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: the
> re is no .runtimeconfig.json file for your single application. Please provide a valid application

I confirmed that the source bundle does have a .runtimeconfig.json file.

Comment: Did you fix? I've had the "no .runtimeconfig.json file" error all day :/

Comment: I get the same error, also confirmed I have the `*.runtimeconfig.json` file

Answer (score 1):

The `.runtimeconfig.json` file is generated when you run the `dotnet publish -o site` command, so check if this command is running properly for you.

If you take a look on the [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-linux-core-tutorial.html), section "To create a source bundle" you have this file, so check the steps that you already did.

Also if you want to force this file to be generated you can add set
`<GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>` directly, but this is normally needed when you are not creating executable files like class libraries.